# Wordpress/SQL Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, search

I am working on a Wordpress site which happens to have a search function built into it for searching for specific data but using custom data and a custom system for it all.

I am using the 'posts' and 'postmeta' tables in my database to query data regarding addresses. Under the column for meta_key I have 2 keys known as 'address1' and 'address2' and under 'meta_value' I have the appropriate data that links with address1 and address2.

I need to write a query that my search system will use to enter only a few words associated with address1 and same with address2 and the query will check for that data within address1 and address2.

---

**Example:**

User enters 'Billstreet' under the address1 text box and 'Test' under the address2 text box the query will check address1 key to see if the field contains 'Billstreet', if it does then it will check address2 to see if it contains 'Test' and if it does then it will return the post_title associated with both of those fields.

---

Here is a query I came up with although I does not particularly work that well, just so you can get an idea of what I am

```
SELECT
  posts.ID,
  posts.post_title,
  postmeta.meta_key,
  postmeta.meta_value
FROM posts
       left join postmeta on postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
WHERE postmeta.meta_key IN ('address1', 'address2')
      AND postmeta.meta_value IN ('BT Correspondence Centre', 'Providence Row')
  AND posts.post_type = 'shops'
  AND posts.post_title LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY (posts.post_title)
```

---

Here is the table structure for how address is set out.

[IMAGE OF TABLE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXnXe.png)

---

If anyone could take a look and either give me some advice or point me in the right direction that would he extremely helpful. Many thanks for taking a look, it is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you should joins on two post_meta tables - one for each address.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example of what you mean @magenta?